In the frame field construction in GR, how do you get the vector field dual to a co-frame?
I am trying to understand the frame-field construction in General Relativity. We basically have four point-wise orthonormal vector fields, one of them being timelike and the other three being spacelike.
In terms of the one-forms, $\{\sigma^0,~\sigma^1,~\sigma^2,~\sigma^3\}$, dual to the vector fields, the metric tensor could be written as
$$ds^2\equiv g=-\sigma^0 \otimes \sigma^0 +\sum_{i=1}^3 \sigma^i \otimes \sigma^i.$$ Now, my question is, if I am given those $\sigma$'s, how do I get the corresponding vector fields?

Not sure if this will answer your question, but you may want to take a quick look at the videos by Eigenchris:  https://www.youtube.com/@eigenchris/playlists.
There are a couple of playlists with videos that discuss covectors (duals) in the context of tensors. Check the "tensor" related playlists.
